# How can I add setAttribute to a var with an onClickEvent?

Tags: javascript, jquery-autocomplete, setattribute

I am using an autocomplete script to make a search field where I can search a list of users called from my database. When the results show in the dropdown, I would like people to be able to click on a user's name and have a fancybox window pop up with their info in it. Here is the script I'm working with:

```
<!-- Autocomplete search field. -->
<div class="input-group" style="float: right; width: 350px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-search"></i></span>
    <input type="text" id="search-tenants" placeholder="Search tenants..."/>
</div>
<script>
    var options = {
        data: [
            <?php 
                foreach ($usersList as $users) { 
                    $count++; ?> '<?=$users->getFirstName()?> <?=$users->getLastName()?>', <? 
                } 
            ?>
        ],
        list: {
            match: { enabled: true },
            onClickEvent: function() {
                $("td.tenant-name .info-card")[0].click();
            },
        }
    };
    $("#search-tenants").easyAutocomplete(options);
</script>
```

If I were to add an anchor and the necessary attributes around the results in the `foreach` statement (like below), the fancybox works as expected, but you can see all of the code in the input field.

```
<?php 
    foreach ($usersList as $users) { 
        $count++; ?> '<a class="info-card" data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="users.php?userid=<?=$users->getUserId()?>&mode=view"><?=$users->getFirstName()?> <?=$users->getLastName()?></a>', <? 
    } 
?>
```

So i'd like to ask: what would be the proper JavaScript way of adding an anchor with class and attributes to the results? I understand there should be a `setAttribute` somewhere, but I'm not sure where.

---

Comment: So you want to know how to add a DOM element to your page via Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery appendTo. http://api.jquery.com/appendto/

You would build up your element (in this case the anchor tag) and then append it to another element.

```
$( "<p>Test</p>" ).appendTo( ".inner" );
```

In this example from the link it appends the paragraph element to each element that has the class "inner".

I hope that helps.